# How do I convert data from DynamoDB scan into a list of just the values?

Tags: python, amazon-dynamodb

In my DynamoDB table I have a primary key of 'repo' and a list of repos in my table.

I run this code to return a scan of the table and this is my response

Code:

```
response = table.scan()
data = response['Items']
print(data)
```

Output:

```
[{'repo': 'MPriv32/TackleTakeHome'}, {'repo': 'MPriv32/fleetwood-k8s-project'}, {'repo': 'MPriv32/terransible'}]
```

I need to convert that into a list of just the item values like this

```
repo_list = ["MPriv32/TackleTakeHome", "MPriv32/fleetwood-k8s-project", "MPriv32/terransible"]
```

I looked online and tried to do this from another post on here

```
response = table.scan()
data = response['Items']
data = json.loads(data)
repo_lists = dict(item.values() for item in data)
print(data)
```

That returned this error when I tried running it

```
    data = json.loads(data)
  File "C:\Users\Mitchell Privett\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\json\__init__.py", line 339, in loads
    raise TypeError(f'the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, '
TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not list
```

I really just need a list of the values from my DynamoDB table and I'm not sure how to get exactly that, without the key in the list as well

Comment: You do not need to do json.loads as its already an object

Comment: You can try repo_lists = [item.repo for item in data]

Comment: @DheerajSharma I changed the code and here's the new error I'm getting "AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'repo'"

Comment: So is there any item in your list/db which do not have repo in it? If yes, you’ll need to handle the situation there

Comment: @DheerajSharma my only key for my DB table is repo, so I don't have to worry about any other items with other keys. My only issue is just trying to extract the values and make a list of just the values

Answer (score 0):

```
response = table.scan()
repo_lists = []
for item in response['Items']:
    if 'repo' in item:
        repo_lists.append(item.repo)
    else:
        print('Not a valid item')
        print(item)
print(repo_lists)
```

Try this, to handle cases where the item in you list doesn’t contains repo key in it.